# custom unobtrusive date validators for dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation, custom-validators

Maybe it's just the way my mind works, but I have a very hard time understanding how you're supposed to do custom unobtrusive validators.  The C# part is easy enough, but the jqueryui adapters are where i get lost.

I've been trying to make a validator that requires a date to be a certain amount of time in the past.  I use this for age validation, to make sure someone has entered a date that is 18 years in the past.

I finally decided to just make it a remote validator, that way the validation uses the same code both client and server side.  Still, i'd be interested in the jquery to make this work.

I wish the Data Annotation Extensions had date functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a lot of information in [Brad Wilson's blog article](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) about unobtrusive validation with asp.net mvc, including creating custom validators.

Based on the following html (should be the output of the TextBox helper)

```
    <input type="text" name="Age"
        data-val="true" 
        data-val-required="This field is required" 
        data-val-minage="You should be 18 years or older, go get your parents!" 
        data-val-minage-value="18" />
    <input type="submit"/>
```

You can add the following javascript to get things validated on the client side:

```
    // Extend date with age calculator
    Date.prototype.age = function (at) {
        var value = new Date(this.getTime());
        var age = at.getFullYear() - value.getFullYear();
        value = value.setFullYear(at.getFullYear());
        if (at < value) --age;
        return age;
    };

    // Add adapter for minimum age validator. Wrap in closure
    (function ($) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("minage", "value");
    } (jQuery));

    // Add client side minimum age validator
    $.validator.methods.minage = function (value, element, params) {

        // If no value is specified, don't validate
        if (value.length == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        var dob = new Date(Date.parse(value));

        if (dob.age(new Date()) < params || dob == 'Invalid Date') {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };
```

Credits for the age calculator are due to [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658522/age-from-date-of-birth-using-jquery/1197028#1197028)

The one thing missing here is globalization, but I figured it was out of the question's scope. btw very easy to implement using the [jquery Globalize plugin](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)

Hope this helps

Comment: That's fantastic.  I think i'm disconnecting on how the adapters work and how jqv interacts.. I've read Brads article a dozen times or more, and something just isn't clicking.