# Comparing two dates using jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I am using Calender plugin to pick two dates respectively from & to. I need to compare value of to always greater than value of from using jQuery as soon as I pick the dates.

I am using the following code

```
var fromDate = $("#from").val();
var toDate = $("#to").val();
if (Date.parse(fromDate) > Date.parse(toDate)) {
    alert("Invalid Date Range!\nStart Date cannot be after End Date!")
    return false;
}
```

And the HTML code is:

```
<input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="" class="datepicker validate[custom[date]]"  tabindex="4" />
<input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="" class="datepicker validate[custom[date]]"  tabindex="4" />
```

If I use jquery validation plugin for comparision:

```
<input value="" class="validate[required,custom[date],future[2009-01-01]" type="text" id="d1" name="d1" />
```

As in http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Comment: Check the existing duplicate .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658522/age-from-date-of-birth-using-jquery

Comment: I use pure JS in my case for it

Comment: if( (new Date(fromDate).getTime() > new Date(toDate).getTime()))

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change your HTML code, you have used same id and name for both the fields. Change it as per below

```
<input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="" class="datepicker validate[custom[date]]"  tabindex="4" />
<input type="text" name="to" id="to" value="" class="datepicker validate[custom[date]]"  tabindex="4" />
```

Comment: Please check this link http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range may be it is helpful for you

Comment: Please use the link I have given above, you have no need to write the javascript to compare dates, it will automatically handle everything, check the link