# Compare two date formats in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-formatting

I have the following :

```
var fit_start_time  = $("#fit_start_time").val(); //2013-09-5
var fit_end_time    = $("#fit_end_time").val(); //2013-09-10

if(Date.parse(fit_start_time)>=Date.parse(fit_end_time)){
    alert("Please select a different End Date.");
}
```

The above code doesn't work. Is there any other solution to the above one?

formatting date as per [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) also dint work for me.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
if(new Date(fit_start_time) <= new Date(fit_end_time))
{//compare end <=, not >=
    //your code here
}
```

Comparing 2 `Date` instances will work just fine. It'll just call `valueOf` implicitly, coercing the `Date` instances to integers, which can be compared using all comparison operators. Well, to be 100% accurate: the `Date` instances will be coerced to the `Number` type, since JS doesn't know of integers or floats, they're all signed 64bit IEEE 754 double precision floating point numbers.

Comment: Actually the same date validation fails . You need to actually do it separately to achieve this. http://jsfiddle.net/neBHQ/3/

Comment: @RoyMJ: your fiddle is flawed: you'll never alert 1, because the dates can't be _both_ `<` _and_ `==`. That, and `==` won't coerce the objects to integers, so you're comparing two distinct objects, and therefore will always be false (try `new Date('2013-09-1') == new Date('2013-09-1')` will always be false). Your fiddle should've been [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jMeMD/)

Comment: @RoyMJ I was just about to write what Elias Van Ootegem has written. You haven't duplicated his code in jsFiddle, you're added an && clause to your condition, making it *have* to be equal as well as be less. This is moronic on so many levels.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem its not working when using different months. If I am using fit_start_time date of November and fit_end_time is date of December. Then it is not validating. Please Help.

Comment: Working only in same month date.

Answer (score 6):

To comapre dates of string format (mm-dd-yyyy).

```
    var job_start_date = "10-1-2014"; // Oct 1, 2014
    var job_end_date = "11-1-2014"; // Nov 1, 2014
    job_start_date = job_start_date.split('-');
    job_end_date = job_end_date.split('-');

    var new_start_date = new Date(job_start_date[2],job_start_date[0],job_start_date[1]);
    var new_end_date = new Date(job_end_date[2],job_end_date[0],job_end_date[1]);

    if(new_end_date <= new_start_date) {
      // your code
    }
```

Comment: doesn't javascript takes month from 0 index? And shouldn't you subtract `-1` from the month part of your `Date` object ? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: month index starts from 0 so ,console.log(new Date('2014','09','1')) will show Oct 1, 2014. Above solution worked for me but i have to pass (month-1) for month argument. If Month value is greater than 11 then we will unexpected date.

Answer (score 3):

As in your example, the `fit_start_time` is not later than the `fit_end_time`.

Try it the other way round:

```
var fit_start_time  = $("#fit_start_time").val(); //2013-09-5
var fit_end_time    = $("#fit_end_time").val(); //2013-09-10

if(Date.parse(fit_start_time) <= Date.parse(fit_end_time)){
    alert("Please select a different End Date.");
}
```

**Update**

Your code implies that you want to see the `alert` with the current variables you have. If this is the case then the above code is correct. If you're intention (as per the implication of the alert `message`) is to make sure their `fit_start_time` variable is a date that is *before* the `fit_end_time`, then your original code is fine, but the data you're getting from the jQuery `.val()` methods is not parsing correctly. It would help if you gave us the actual HTML which the selector is sniffing at.

Comment: @RoyMJ It depends what you mean by 'work'. It works, it's just not giving you the behaviour you expect.

Answer (score 2):

try with `new Date(obj).getTime()`

```
if( new Date(fit_start_time).getTime() > new Date(fit_end_time).getTime() )
{
    alert(fit_start_time + " is greater."); // your code
}
else if( new Date(fit_start_time).getTime() < new Date(fit_end_time).getTime() )
{
    alert(fit_end_time + " is greater."); // your code
}
else
{
    alert("both are same!"); // your code
}
```

Comment: Actually this works if you separate the `>` and `=` comparisons into two steps.. wierd.

Comment: This code creates the same `Date` instances over and over again, please, don't... just assing them to `fit_start_time` and `fit_end_time`, to avoid pointless overhead

Answer (score 0):

This is already in :

[Age from Date of Birth using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658522/age-from-date-of-birth-using-jquery)

or alternatively u can use Date.parse() as in

```
var date1 = new Date("10/25/2011");
var date2 = new Date("09/03/2010");
var date3 = new Date(Date.parse(date1) - Date.parse(date2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it the other way:

```
var start_date  = $("#fit_start_time").val(); //05-09-2013
var end_date    = $("#fit_end_time").val(); //10-09-2013
var format='dd-MM-y';
    var result= compareDates(start_date,format,end_date,format);
    if(result==1)/// end date is less than start date
    {
            alert('End date should be greater than Start date');
    }



OR:
if(new Date(start_date) >= new Date(end_date))
{
    alert('End date should be greater than Start date');
}
```

Comment: i think u missed out `compareDates` function if your above code has to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
let Date1 = "04-18-2023" // 18 April, 2023 
let Date2 = "05-01-2023" // 01 May, 2023 
if(new Date(Date1) < new Date(Date2)) 
{ 
 console.log("Date1 is less than Date2")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

var startDate= "11-11-2014"; // 10th Nov 2021

var endDate= "11-1-2014";

startDate= startDate.split('-');

endDate= endDate.split('-');

var newStartDate= new Date(startDate[2],startDate[0]-1,startDate[1]);

var newEndDate= new Date(endDate[2],endDate[0]-1,endDate[1]);

if(newEndDate<= newStartDate) {

}

Comment: This looks more like a response to [this answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26655449/2227743) rather than a new answer...