# How to compare two dates with different formats in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two dates:

```
D1 = 2017-05-01 00:00:00 and
D2 = Thu Jun 01 2017 16:12:08 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) "d".
```

How can I compare these two dates in javascript?

```
if (D1>D2) { do something } else { do something}
```

Comment: change them to make them same format then compare

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen. nothing. just find a way to make them in similar format.

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask]. You've told us nothing about the source, what you want to accomplish or what you have researched and what you have tried

Comment: @JayMomaya This is not a coding service. ! "just find a way" is kinda do this for me and make it work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two date formats in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913579/compare-two-date-formats-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Question edited to change jquery to javascript due to obvious misunderstanding of the difference between jquery and javascript

Comment: Not sure why this was voted 'too broad', even from the original unedited question.  The close reason just shows the first reason voted - it was also off-topic (not enough info) and a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why jquery? simply Do with [`new Date()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjT5JDBvJzUAhXJpo8KHa3dA5sQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate&usg=AFQjCNHKCWPSFyznKUiCi5MHWYxu5toVIg&sig2=G8e27IhpTL86Gh8TWElAXg)

```js
var D1 = '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
var D2 = 'Thu Jun 01 2017 16:12:08 GMT+0530';

console.log(new Date(D1).getTime(),new Date(D2).getTime())
```