# how do i compare 2 dates to check whether event passed or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

i'm trying to show `notifications` to `users` **only** for `today's` entered matches some date in this format `2017/11/13 15:02` from `record`

NOTE:`2017/11/13 15:02` will always change, used for the sake of comparison

**in pseudo code**

```
 if(today's date passed and dont match 2017/11/13 15:02){
    //don't send notification
 }else{
   //send notification
}
```

**i have tried something like this**

```
var comparisionDate = '2017/11/13 15:02';

var todaysDate = new Date();  // current date

// further i don't know to compare

if(comparisionDate == todaysDate ){
   //send notifications
}else{
  // don't show notification
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913579/compare-two-date-formats-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The getTime() method will give you the time stamp in milliseconds since the epoch, you can use it with the new Date, Date.parse() however already returns a time stamp.

```js
var comparisionDate = Date.parse('2017/11/13 15:02');

var todaysDate = new Date();  // current date

// further i don't know to compare

if(comparisionDate == todaysDate.getTime() ){
   //send notifications
   
   alert("Today's date " + todaysDate.getTime() + " equals " + comparisionDate);
}else{
  // don't show notification
  alert("Today's date " + todaysDate.getTime() + " Not equals " + comparisionDate);
}
```

Comment: for this **date** also `var comparisionDate = Date.parse('2017/11/10 15:02');   
`    it is showing `not equal `  **must be equal?**

Comment: It computes time in milliseconds , so if one second difference doesn't really matters, divide both time stamps by 1000 and then compare, for minutes by 60000, etc