# Django : datepicker in ModelForm

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

in the model, I have two fields like

```
from_date = models.DateField()
to_date = models.DateField()
```

in the forms i have defined it as

```
widgets =  {
            'from_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
            'to_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
           }
```

in the base html, I have  written the jQuery code for datepicker as

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker(
          {
            minDate : 0,
            beforeShowDay : $.datepicker.noWeekends
          }
        );
    });

    </script>
```

I have zero knowledge in javascript and jQuery, all I want to implement is 
`to_date` should be always greater than `from_date`. How do I do that?

my model

```
class Leave(models.Model):

    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = DEPARTMENT_CHOICES)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = DESIGNATION_CHOICES)
    type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = CHOICES)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
    reporting_manager = models.CharField(max_length = 50, choices = MANAGER_CHOICES)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length= 180)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 15, choices = STATUS_CHOICES)
    reason_reject = models.CharField(('reason for rejection'),max_length=50, default = '-') #blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
    last_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my forms.py

```
class LeaveRequestForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    fields = ("name", "employee_ID" ,"department", "designation", "type_of_leave", "from_date", "to_date", "reporting_manager", "reason")
    model = Leave

    widgets =  {
        'name': Textarea(attrs = {'cols' : 20, 'rows': 1}),
        'employee_ID' : Textarea(attrs = {'cols' : 20, 'rows': 1}),
        'from_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
        'to_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
        'reason_reject' : forms.HiddenInput()

    }
```

Comment: i think you should try to find the solution in the internet, try it and if you get troubles do new research and only after it, create new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
 var from_date = models.DateField();//Your From Date
    var to_date = models.DateField();//Your To Date

    if(new Date(to_date) > new Date(from_date))//This Condition Compares both Dates 
    {
         //Your Code
    }
```

For More details refer [Date Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913579/compare-two-date-formats-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Create the Django Models as below

```
class Request(models.Model):
    from_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now, blank = True)
    to_date = models.DateField(default = timezone.now, blank = True)
```

Write the Form for above model as below

```
class TimestampForm (forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TimestampForm, self).clean()
        from_date = cleaned_data.get("from_date")
        to_date = cleaned_data.get("to_date")
        if from_date > to_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("'From date' cannot be a later time than 'To date'.")
        if to_date > (timezone.now()):
            raise forms.ValidationError("'To date' cannot be a future time.")
        return cleaned_data
    from_date = forms.DateField(label = 'From Date * ', widget = DateWidget(attrs = {'id':"from_date"}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version = 3))
    to_date = forms.DateField(label = 'To Date', widget = DateWidget(attrs = {'id':"to_date"}, usel10n = True, bootstrap_version = 3))
```

With above model and form you don't have to do any modification with HTML

Comment: I already have a model and modelform, check my updated question. My bad for not sharing it before

Comment: could you please tell with my default form and model

Comment: and rather comparing it can't we disable all the dates that fall behind the `from_date` such that were there's no room for the user to select `to_date` lesser than `from_date`.