# compare date in javascript format 06/01/2014 13:24

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, format, compare

I am trying to compare two dates in javascript, which are in two input type="text", and that have the format "06/11/2013 13:24".

Any idea of how to compare them?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to compare the date part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare dates with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will do what you want - construct one for each date, then just compare them using the usual operators.

For example, subtracting date1 from date2 will give you the number of milliseconds between two dates.

You can get the number of seconds by dividing the milliseconds by 1000, and rounding the number:

```
var seconds = Math.round((date2-date1)/1000);
```

You could then divide by 60 to get the minutes, again by 60 to get the hours, then by 24 to get the days (and so on).

Here's how you might get a figure in the format dd:hh:mm

```
window.minutesPerDay = 60 * 24;

function pad(number) {
    var result = "" + number;
    if (result.length < 2) {
        result = "0" + result;
    }

    return result;
}

function millisToDaysHoursMinutes(millis) {
    var seconds = millis / 1000;
    var totalMinutes = seconds / 60;

    var days = totalMinutes / minutesPerDay;
    totalMinutes -= minutesPerDay * days;
    var hours = totalMinutes / 60;
    totalMinutes -= hours * 60; 

    return days + ":" + pad(hours) + ":" + pad(totalMinutes);
}

var date1 = new Date("06/11/2013 13:24"),
    date2 = new Date("07/11/2013 13:24"),
    milliseconds = date2 - date1;

alert(millisToDaysHoursMinutes(milliseconds));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/L5dEC/)

I took the millisToDaysHoursMinutes function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528382/javascript-show-milliseconds-as-dayshoursmins-without-seconds).

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse string to Date - object:

```
var firstDate = new Date("06/11/2013 13:24");
var secondDate = new Date(youSecondDateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Age from Date of Birth using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658522/age-from-date-of-birth-using-jquery)

Possibly a **duplicate** question to above but the answers is

```
var startDt=document.getElementById("startDateId").value;
var endDt=document.getElementById("endDateId").value;

if( (new Date(startDt).getTime() > new Date(endDt).getTime()))
{
    //perform desired operation here
}
```